# Python, how to flexibly create subclass?

Tags: python

The detail question is I have a plenty of classes, say A, B, C, D...Z, they're all derived from 'Base'. They all have a method set_value. Now I need to have some subclasses to override set_value of A...Z, the implement of new set_value are the same for all. Theoretically, I can do something like class AA(A), class BB(B)... but it's tedious and not compact, I am not sure if one or all of A...Z need a subclass, I only want to create it when I create an object of the subclass.

In C++, I can do this easily via template:

```
template<class T>
class CCustom : public T
{
};
CCustom<vector<int> > obj1;
CCustom<list<char> > obj2;
```

Add some demo Python scripts here to help explain my question:

```
class Base:
def set_value(self):
    pass

class A(Base):
    def set_value(self):
        print('A.set_value')

class B(Base):
    def set_value(self):
        print('B.set_value')

class C(Base):
    def set_value(self):
        print('C.set_value')


def more_set_value():
    print('all subclasses do this')

class AA(A):
    def set_value(self):
        more_set_value()
        super().set_value()

class BB(B):
    def set_value(self):
        more_set_value()
        super().set_value()

class CC(C):
    def set_value(self):
        more_set_value()
        super().set_value()

a = AA()
b = BB()
c = CC()

a.set_value()
b.set_value()
c.set_value()
```

You can see AA, BB and CC are almost same. It's boring when there are hundreds this kind of class need to put in my project. I reckon there must be a way to write a factory function, to create AA, BB and CC dynamically, so that I can do following:

```
  AA = create_custom_subclass(A)
  a = AA()
  a.set_value()
```

Comment: Mixins, class factories, maybe even class decorators. There are many options, you need to explain the problem, not ask for an equivalent to C++. Think in Python. ;-)

Comment: Templates where introduced in C++ in order to deal with the same code for multiple types. But this problem obviously does not exist in Python. Besides I'm not sure how overriding base method is related to templates? The question is not clear at all.

Comment: Also, just to check: You know you don't need setters in Python, right? I think it would be better if you showed some real code as well. You might not need this complex type system at all (and then again you may).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes are [first-class citizens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen) in Python, i.e. you can treat them like any other object. For example you can do a simple factory:

```
def create_custom_subclass(cls):
    class sub(cls):
        def set_value(self):
            more_set_value()
            super().set_value()
    return sub

AA = create_custom_subclass(A)
a = AA()
a.set_value()
```

Or you can do a mixin (uses less memory then a factory):

```
class Mixin:
    def set_value(self):
        more_set_value()
        super().set_value()

class AA(Mixin, A):
    pass
```

Comment: The Mixin seems the right way to go for me, with the small amount of information given.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear to me what it is you want to do, but I'll try to give you some pointers so to speak.

Unlinke C++, Python uses a [dynamic type system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system), i.e. a variable can be assigned an object of any type. This gives you a whole range of possibilities.

```
class CustomClass(object):
    def __init__(self, obj_of_t_class):
        self.obj_of_t_class = obj_of_t_class

    def set_value(self, value):
        self.obj_of_t_class.some_method(value)
        # do something else here
```

As long as `obj_of_t_class` has the methods you try to call, Python doesn't care if it's of type `A`, `B` or `Z`.

This should be roughly equivalent to what you want to do with the C++ template class.